# How to Fix CORB with MIME type text/html, Chrome Extension 73

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cross-origin-read-blocking

What is the correct way to pass the code from myscript.js to background.js?

I have

myscript.js

```
function fox2(){
{
    var url = 'https://sub.domain.com'
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', url, true);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
          var parser = new DOMParser();
          source_code = parser.parseFromString(xhr.responseText, "text/html");   
          var a = source_code;
          console.log(a)
        }
      };
      xhr.send();
    }
     }
fox2();
```

Background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "nuevo.js"});
});
```

Error: Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response  with MIME type text/html

I know that the solution is to use the code in Background, But How should I do it?.

Thanks.